# kubernetes nginx ingress giving 503 and 404

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

While creating Ingress rules to the existing APIs is using TLS mandatory?

I am getting 404 and 503 error codes to all the APIs except given without any path.

I am using nginx ingress controller.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /test
        backend:
          serviceName: example-project
          servicePort: 8085
```

This is the ingress rule I created:

`gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.10` - version of controller

Comment: is it mandatory to use healthz?

Comment: Can you provide `service` and `pods` configurations of your application? And also the result of the `kubectl describe $name_of_your_service` command.

Comment: @HemaMahadevu it's not mandatory to use the healthz

Comment: @HemaMahadevu 404 comes when there is issue in path to service. 503 come when your request reach to service but there is no running ready pod behind the service. 502 comes when there pod running behind service but there issue in your application.

Answer (score 0):

In K8s nginx-ingress. By default some nginx have we configured that may block your service.

```
kubectl describe configMap nginx-configuration -n ingress-nginx
```

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/146db437945a130d675540285fe02fa9639ba1f0/docs/user-guide/configmap.md

Answer (score 0):

`example-project` must be of type NodePort. Because by default is ClusterIP

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-project
...
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
...
```